# VS Code PHP Debugging without xdebug.remote_autostart=1

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-code

How can I use the PHP debugger withing VS Code without the following setting in PHP.INI?

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

This setting makes apache extremely slow.

Before I used PHPStorm and this supplied a parameter un the URL that triggered the debugger. I wonder if this is possible in VS Code too.

I use VS Code 1.53.2 with the PHP extension pck from Felix Becker.

Before someone asks: I switched to VS code although I loved PHPStorm because PHPStorm is unusable on my Surface pro X due to bad performance. VS Code has a Windows Arm implementation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use xdebug v3 instead of v2:

**For Xdebug v3.x.x:**

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = //path to xdebug dll file
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9000
```

In xdebug v3 you can use `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` instead of `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`

> make a simple `test.php` file, put a `phpinfo();` statement in there,
> then copy the output and paste it into the [Xdebug installation
> wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php). It will analyze it and give you tailored installation
> instructions for your environment.

If you are using "PHP Debug" extension by "Felix Becker" in "VS Code" you will see more instructions at extension's details.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. Debugging is much faster with the V3 setup.

Comment: Also on my Surface pro X that is very slow with any JAVA application due to x86 emulation on ARM, VS Studio, Apache and PHP run like clockwork, thanks once more!